# Definite Integral of $\int_{-L}^{L} \cos(\frac{nπx}L)\cos(\frac{mπx}L)dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Please can someone explain why I need to substitute the values of integers $m$ and $n$ in the definite integral:
$$I=\int_{-L}^{L} \cos\left(\frac{nπx}L\right)\cos\left(\frac{mπx}L\right)dx = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{$n \neq m$} \\
L, & \text{$n = m \neq 0$} \\
2L, & \text{$n = m = 0$}
\end{cases}$$
before doing the integration.

For example, if I substitute $n=m=0$, or $n=m\neq0$ before doing the integration I get the expected result after performing the simplified definite integrals:

Substitute $n=m=0$:
$$I=\int_{-L}^{L} \cos\left(0\right)\cos\left(0\right)dx$$
$$=\left[1\right]_{-L}^{L}$$
$$=2L$$
Substitute $n=m\neq0$:
$$I=\int_{-L}^{L} \cos^{2}\left(\frac{mπx}L\right)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L} \left[\cos\left(\frac{2mπx}L\right)+1\right]dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{L}{2mπ}\sin\left(\frac{2mπx}L\right)+x \right]_{-L}^{L}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left\{ 0+L-0-(-L) \right\}=L$$

When I assume any integer for $n$ and $m$ before doing the integration and use the trigonometric identity: $\cos A \cos B = \frac 12\left[\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)\right]$ to solve this, I get the wrong result.

I have shown my steps below, so it would be great if someone could show what I'm doing wrong.
$$ I=\int_{-L}^{L} \cos\left(\frac{nπx}L\right)\cos\left(\frac{mπx}L\right)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L} \cos\left(\frac{(n+m)πx}L\right)+\cos\left(\frac{(n-m)πx}L\right)dx$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{L}{(n+m)π}\sin\left(\frac{(n+m)πx}L\right)+\frac{L}{(n-m)π}\sin\left(\frac{(n-m)πx}L\right)\right]_{-L}^{L} $$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\left\{ \frac{L}{(n+m)π}\sin\left((n+m)π\right)+\frac{L}{(n-m)π}\sin\left((n-m)π\right)-\frac{L}{(n+m)π}\sin\left(-(n+m)π\right)-\frac{L}{(n-m)π}\sin\left(-(n-m)π\right)\right\}  $$
When $n=m=0$, this evaluates to $0$, disagreeing with the previous result.

When $n=m\neq0$, this evaluates to $0$, also disagreeing with the previous result.

When $n \neq m$, it evaluates to 0, which is the correct answer.

Maybe it is invalid to assume any value for integers $n$ and $m$ before going the integration? If so, why?

Comment: When $n=m$ you are dividing by $0$

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $n=m$, you have $m-n=0$ and your general calculation fails.

To see what is going wrong for simplicity, you can set $L=\pi$ and consider the simple example:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\cos(x)\;dx.
$$

Applying the trig identity to the integrand, you have
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x)+\cos(0x))
$$

But
$$
\int \cos(0x)\;dx \ne \frac{1}{0}\sin(0x)
$$

Comment: Thanks. I now see my error - I have a $0$ in the denominator for the general calculation, which is undefined.